# Why is PHP/WordPress echoing a blank line here?

Tags: php, wordpress, whitespace

I have a very simple [loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) for an archive page at a website:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()): ?>
<div id="thumbs-container">
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
    <div <?php post_class('thumb'); ?>>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full',array('alt'=>get_the_title(),'title'=>null)); ?>
        <div class="thumb-desc">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'Description',true); ?></p>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endif; endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php else: get_template_part('no-results'); endif; ?> // <--problem here?
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And here is the `no-results` template *in its entirety*:

```
<h2>Nothing here yet.</h2>
<p>Please <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">return to the home page</a>.</p>
```

Since the archive is currently empty, the contents of `no-results.php` are shown, as expected. A glance at the page source shows nothing (not even white space) between the `<h2>` and its containing `<div>`, however the `<h2>` is pushed down one line on the page and the Developer Console shows me an empty text node above it:

[image: A string of spaces above an H2 element]

Sloppy whitespace is one thing; whitespace that actually affects my layout is another. Is there something I'm missing which might be causing this?

Comment: where is the part that contains <div id="content"> ????
the problem should be there

Comment: `<div id="content">` is in the `header.php` file and it is on the very last line with no whitespace afterwards. Furthermore, it is included on every page and I'd never seen a problem before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you by any chance use Notepad to create your `no-results` template?

I would guess that your template starts with a [UTF-8 Byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Notepad inserts it by default when you save a file with the UTF-8 encoding. Some other text editors also do that, but usually have an option to turn it off.

Use an editor that doesn't insert a BOM, or, considering your template doesn't contain any non-ASCII characters anyway, simply save it as ASCII/ANSI.

Comment: Yep! Notepad++ gives the option to omit the BOM and there we have it. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are close thing if before the while loop?

`<?php endif; endwhile; ?>`    Seems wrong because you open the if fist and the while second so you should close them in most recent first order e.g.
`<?php endwhile; endif; ?>`

Comment: No, there are two `if`s. They are closed in the correct order.

Comment: Indeed sorry for not looking more closely :S

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php if(have_posts()): ?>
    <div id="thumbs-container"><-- this will echoed if there is content
    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
        <div <?php post_class('thumb'); ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('full',array('alt'=>get_the_title(),'title'=>null)); ?>
            <div class="thumb-desc">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'Description',true); ?></p>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div> <-- here should be the closing tag of thumbs-container
    <?php endif; endwhile; ?>
    </div> <-- the closing tag will be always echoed better moved up
    <?php else: get_template_part('no-results'); endif; ?> // <--problem here?
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

i think you should move the closing tag wich screwed your markup

Comment: You made the same mistake as JohnKlehm. The `endif` closes the `if` inside the `while` loop (at the end of the 4th line). The closing `div` tag is positioned correctly.